# What is the forSome keyword in Scala for?

Tags: scala

I found the following code snippet:

```
List[T] forSome { type T }
```

The `forSome` looks like a method, but my friend told me it's a keyword.

I googled it, but found few documents about `forSome`. What does it mean, and where can I get some documents about it?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `forSome` keyword is used to define existential types in Scala. There's this Scala [glossary](http://docs.scala-lang.org/glossary/#existential_type) page explaining what they are. I couldn't find a place in the Scala docs explaining them in detail, so [here](http://scalada.blogspot.com/2008/01/existential-types.html) is a blog article I found on Google explaining how they are useful.

Update: you can find a precise definition of existential types in the [Scala specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types) but it is quite dense.

To summarize some of the posts I linked to, existential types are useful when you want to operate on something but don't care about the details of the type in it. For example, you want to operate on arrays but don't care *what kind* of array:

```
def printFirst(x : Array[T] forSome {type T}) = println(x(0))
```

which you could also do with a type variable on the method:

```
def printFirst[T](x : Array[T]) = println(x(0))
```

but you may not want to add the type variable in some cases. You can also add a bound to the type variable:

```
def addToFirst(x : Array[T] forSome {type T <: Integer}) = x(0) + 1
```

Also see [this blog post](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) which is where I got this example from.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/news/roadmap-next.html - "forSome syntax is eliminated."

Comment: forSome is slated for removal in the "Don Giovanni" release: https://www.scala-lang.org/news/roadmap-next.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Scala, but your question picked up my interest and started Googling.

I found that in [Scala's changelog](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43#ChangesinVersion2627Jul2007):

> "It is now possible to define existential types using the new keyword
>   `forSome`. An existential type has the form `T forSome {Q}` where `Q` is a
>   sequence of value and/or type declarations. "

Comment: Some info could be found also in [Scala Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), on 26th page

Comment: current spec: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types