# Lower type bound on Scala field in mutable, covariant class?

Tags: scala, covariance

I want to create a covariant class which is mutable, so I need to add a lower type bound to the setter method.  But I also want the setter method to set a field, so I guess the field needs to have the same type bound?

```
class Thing[+F](initialValue: F) {

    private[this] var secondValue: Option[G >: F] = None

    def setSecondValue[G >: F](v: G) = {
        this.secondValue = Some(v)
     }
}
```

The method compiles fine.  But the field called secondValue doesn't compile at all, with the error message:

```
    Multiple markers at this line
        - ']' expected but '>:' found.
        - not found: type G
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the `forSome` construct, which introduces `G` as existential type:

```
class Thing[+F](initialValue: F) {
  private[this] var secondValue: Option[G] forSome { type G >: F} = None

  def setSecondValue[G >: F](v: G) = {
    this.secondValue = Some(v)
  }
}
```

In your original code for `secondValue`, `G` has been pulled out of thin air, i.e., it hasn't been introduced properly. In case of `setSecondValue` the user (or the compiler) binds `G` at call site, but for a field that's not an option (especially, since yours is private). Read more about `forSome` and existential types in Scala [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444958/what-does-the-key-word-forsome-mean-in-scala), [here](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) or [here](http://existentialtype.net/2008/03/09/higher-rank-impredicative-polymorphism-in-scala/).

Comment: Perfect - does what I want.  I tried using forSome on the method and that works too: def setSecondAroma(secondAroma: G forSome {type G>: F}) = ...

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't know if using forSome G in setSecondValue has any (dis)advantages when compared to just having a regular type argument G. Should you know/find out, please post it here.

Comment: Note that type `G` in the field has nothing to do with type `G` in the method here.

Answer (score 11):

@mhs answer is right.

You can also use wildcard syntax (like in java), which has exactly the same meaning:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Thing[+F](initialValue: F) {
  private[this] var secondValue: Option[_ >: F] = None

  def setSecondValue[G >: F](v: G) = {
    this.secondValue = Some(v)
  }

  def printSecondValue() = println(secondValue)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Thing

scala> val t = new Thing(Vector("first"))
t: Thing[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[java.lang.String]] = Thing@1099257

scala> t.printSecondValue()
None

scala> t.setSecondValue(Seq("second"))

scala> t.printSecondValue()
Some(List(second))
```

Comment: hmm, i think i accepted too fast.  this seems a more elegant solution.