# Using Wildcards in Scala

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> trait Thingy[A] {}
defined trait Thingy
```

what's the difference between:

```
scala> def f[A](x: Thingy[A]): Thingy[A] = x
f: [A](x: Thingy[A])Thingy[A]
```

and

```
scala> def g(x: Thingy[_]): Thingy[_] = x
g: (x: Thingy[_])Thingy[_]
```

The following shows a difference:

```
scala> def foo[A](x: Thingy[A]): Thingy[A] = f(x)
foo: [A](x: Thingy[A])Thingy[A]

scala> def bar[A](x: Thingy[A]): Thingy[A] = g(x)
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Thingy[_$2] where type _$2
 required: Thingy[A]
       def bar[A](x: Thingy[A]): Thingy[A] = g(x)
                                              ^
```

But, please explain the difference between `f` and `g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `g` says: given a `Thingy` with some type parameter, it returns a `Thingy` with some (possibly different) type parameter. E.g. this would be a legal implementation:

```
def g(x: Thingy[_]): Thingy[_] = new Thingy[Int] {}
```

Now it should be obvious that `bar` won't work with this definition of `g`, since it always returns a `Thingy[Int]` regardless of `A`. And since the compiler only uses the type of `g` (not the implementation), it has to reject `bar`.

Comment: I would also add [`forSome`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444958/what-is-the-forsome-keyword-in-scala-for) near equivalent example  `type LL = List[X] forSome {type X}; def g(x: LL): LL = List[Int]()`

Comment: I've thought about mentioning it and decided not to, actually :)

Comment: yeah, "Thingy with **some** type parameter" kinda alludes :)

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent syntax for `g` would be:

```
def g[A, B](x: Thingy[A]): Thingy[B] = x
```

... except that would complain because `A` and `B` are not equivalent. With `_`, you tell the compiler to discard any information about `A` and `B`. So it can't prove that in `bar`, the type of the input of `g` is the same type as the output.

Comment: This is close to true, but not quite: they are obviously not equivalent because the version in the question compiles, and yours doesn't! The difference is that in your case the caller chooses `B`, in the version with `_` the implementation does.