# Universally Quantified Types in Haskell and Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell

[Existentially quantified types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types) explains:

> any use of a lowercase type implicitly begins with a `forall` keyword, so the two type declarations for map are equivalent, as are the declarations below:

```
id :: a -> a
id :: forall a . a -> a
```

Given Scala's [scala.Predef#identity](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Predef$.html), is there a `forall` equivalent, i.e. per Haskell's above second function?

Comment: I don't know much scala but isn't it just the same as in the citation? I would assume the `A` in `def identity[A](x: A): A` to be a `forall A` as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no *explicit* `forall` in Scala, but it has equivalents to the different ways explicit `forall`s are used in Haskell:

1. To enable `ScopedTypeVariables`: not necessary, as Scala type variables are scoped by default.
2. For existential types: Scala supports them directly.
3. For higher-rank types, i.e. ones which have a `forall` nested under function arrows: consider this example:

   ```
   f2 :: (forall a. a->a) -> Int -> Int
   f2 f x = f x
   ```

   In Scala `[A](A => A)` can't be used directly, but

   ```
   trait Poly1 {
     def apply[A](x: A): A
   }
   ```

   is equivalent to it, so you can implement `f2`:

   ```
   def f2(p: Poly1, x: Int) = p(x)
   ```

Comment: I did not quite understand your third point, possibly because I am not familiar with what the Haskell example is: What exactly is the benefit of the Poly1 approach over a standard `Int => Int`?

Comment: @Adowrath For this case, there's no difference. Consider `def f3(p: Poly1, x: Int, y: Bool) = (f3(x), f3(y))` instead (unlike Haskell, Scala also could use `Any => Any` here, but it'll give a different, and less precise, return type).

Comment: Interesting. I thought this would be possible with the existential type as well, but it seems my understanding wasn't sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am not a Scala expert, but my understanding is that all Scala type parameters are universally quantified (i.e. declared with a `forall`) *unless* they are explicitly quantified with `forSome`. See, for instance:

[What is the forSome keyword in Scala for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9444958/866915)

In Haskell we use the `forall` keyword to declare existential types. It may seem counter-intuitive to use `forall` when we mean `for some`, but it can be done using the logical equivalence of the following statements:

```
(forSome x. P(x))  implies  Q   

(forall x. P(x)    implies  Q)
```

Here Q is a statement not containing *x*.