# Scala - Difference between parametric method and forSome

Tags: scala, generics, types

In Scala:

```
def rules[T]: Array[Rule[T]]= { ... }
```

vs.

```
def rules: Array[Rule[T]] forSome {type T} = { ... }
```

They are not the same  because in some cases only the latter one is working.

Comment: Not an answer, but the most important difference: there are practically zero cases where you want the latter version.

Answer (score 0):

forSome marks an existential type. Existential types may be used for client side type variance, which might be required for your use case. You can read more under this question.

[What is the forSome keyword in Scala for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444958/what-is-the-forsome-keyword-in-scala-for)

or in the linked article

http://scalada.blogspot.de/2008/01/existential-types.html

Comment: But I want to know what is the difference between both idioms