# scala multi dimensional array representation in repl

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and I wrote this in repl

```
val xx = Array.ofDim [String](3,4) 
xx: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, null, null, null), Array(null, null, 
         null, null), Array(null, null, null, null))

@ val yy = Array.ofDim [Int](3,4) 
  yy: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0))

@ val ss = Array(xx, yy)
```

which resulted in this

```
ss: Array[Array[_1] forSome { type _1 >: Array[Int] with Array[String] <: Array[_1] forSome { type _1 >: Int with String } }] = Array(
Array(Array(null, null, null, null), Array(null, null, null, null), Array(null, null, null, null)),
Array(Array(0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0))
)
```

can someone please explain what does this mean

```
Array[_1] forSome { type _1 >: Array[Int] with Array[String] <: Array[_1] forSome { type _1 >: Int with String } }
```

specially the >: .....<: ....   part.
by the way I am using scala 2.13.

cheers,

es

Comment: Since `xx`  & `yy` have different types, then `Array(xx, yy)` would be an `Array[Any]` which is not very usable, the weird type is because `Array` is invariant thus `Array[Any]` would not be the appropriate type. - In general, don't use `Arrays` and don't mix types, if you are new to the language you probably are doing something wrong, maybe explain the meta-problem you are trying to solve. Also, I invite you to join the official **Scala** **Discord** server to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have just started to learn scala and fooling around with it, thanks fir the discord tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forSome` keyword in Scala creates an existential type. That is a type that you don't know or don't care what it precisely is, you can just provide conditions for it. More [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444958/what-is-the-forsome-keyword-in-scala-for/9444996).

The `<:` and `:>` operators mean type bound. A definition like `type A <: B` means, that type `A` is a subtype of `B`. And the definition `type A >: B` means that `A` is a supertype of `B`.

In this case (last snippet), it means that you have an Array with a parameter `_1` about which we know that it is a supertype of `Array[Int] with Array[String]` and a subtype of `Array[_1] forSome { type _1 >: Int with String }`